# How do I pass binary payloads in RestRequest and RestResponse with Grapevine 4.0?

Tags: c#, grapevine

I am trying to figure out how to pass binary data with Grapevine.  I found this link: https://github.com/sukona/Grapevine/issues/208 but didn't see any follow up code.  I haven't been able to find any other pointers to how to do this.

Comment: Request/Response are http and binary data must be converted to a Base 64 String.

Answer (score 0):

The `Payload` property on the request is a helper that reads the `InputStream` property of the the underlying [`HttpListenerRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httplistenerrequest.inputstream?view=netframework-4.8) into a string for parsing. As long as no previous route had read this stream (it is a read-once stream), you can access this stream and read it directly.

```cs
public static void GetBinaryData(HttpContext context)
{
    if (context.Request is HttpRequest request)
    {
        var input = request.Advanced.InputStream;
        // Do what you want to get your data out of the stream
    }
}
```

From there, you can read the stream and convert it as you see fit.